# How to make IE 6 play MPEG-4 HTTP stream?

Tags: internet-explorer, http, video-streaming, playback, mpeg-4

I have MPEG-4 video stream at http://pool.amursu.ru/video.mpg and I can to watch it using Chrome or Firefox, but Internet Explorer 6 doesn't play it, just attempts to load it forever (I think, it waits for end of file, which, probably, won't ever happen).

I've tried to use Flowplayer and JWplayer, but with no success:

```
<div id="container">Loading the player...</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
  jwplayer("container").setup({
    flashplayer: "/jwplayer/player.swf",
    width: 800,
    height: 450,
    levels: [
      {
        bitrate: 300,
        file: "http://pool.amursu.ru/video.mpg",
        width: 800
      }
    ],
    provider: "http",
    "http.startparam":"starttime"
  });
</script>
```

It's available on http://pool.amursu.ru/

The videostream is done by D-Link DCS-2130 webcam and proxied by nginx.

Any ideas to get it working in IE?

P.S> I can set video/mpeg MIME-type for video stream, but it brokes playback in Chrome and doesn't help for IE.

**UPD**:

For now I've done an unfair solution: found an URL in camera's web interface, from where I can get a single videoframe, proxied it with Nginx, and refresh it every second with javascript. Totally unfair, but works everywhere. http://pool.amursu.ru/

Comment: [IE6 died](http://ie6funeral.com/) a couple of years ago [and Microsoft sent flowers](http://blog.seattlepi.com/microsoft/2010/03/04/microsoft-sends-flowers-to-internet-explorer-6-funeral/).  Do you *really* need to support it?

Comment: Yes, it's sad, but I need to. And newer IE versions too.